# Run testng.xml from command prompt. I have jar that is created from Maven Project. Surefireplugin is not solving my purpose

Tags: maven, testng

What i have

> Jar created from maven project
>   TestNG.xml file

What i want

> Want to run testng.xml from command prompt

What i tried

> Used surefire plugin in pom then executed mvn test command.

What is problem then ?

> Surefire plugin will need. src folder and every time it will build project.

Any solution available ? Using jar file and testng . I dont want to use src or bin

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [multi-module](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) maven project.

For example with two modules, A and B. Module A will build the jar file, and in module B, you can specify A as a dependency, and run your tests from there.

Comment: Is this to avoid building project on every execution ?

Comment: Yes, when build module B, previously built jar file from module A will be used.